# Android Studio with Cordova CLI

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-studio, gradle

I'd like to use Cordova CLI to create a new project and then import it to android studio to continue my work. Importing to android studio changes the project folder hierarchy (Adds everything under src/main/java) which would break the CLI going forward. How can I keep both android studio and cordova CLI happy at the same time ?!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your are created your  project under `Hellocordova` directory, before doing import build your project using the command `cordova build android`.

Use this as import location `Hellocordova\platforms\android`.

It will works fine